# ansible deploy container to remote from local image

Tags: docker, ansible

i have created images on my local instance want to deploy container from that image
here is my playbook code

```
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
 become: yes
 become_method: sudo
 tasks:
 - name: Install pip
   apt: name=python3-pip state=present

 - name: Running the container
   docker_container:
     name: tmep
     image: ipdata:latest
     pull: no

 - name: Check if container is running
   shell: docker ps
```

when running this playbook it sends me this error

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error pulling image ipdata:latest - 404 Client Error: Not Found (\"b'{\"message\":\"pull access denied for ipdata, repository does not exist or may require \\'docker login\\': denied: requested access to the resource is denied\"}'\")"}
```

so my questions are

1. is it possible to
2. or do i need to copy all file on remote then create image and then create container from that image
3. that will be great if some one share a sample code which will create image and then deploy containers .

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62056609/edit) and fix the formatting. You may want to add the `[docker]` tag to your question, since it isn't really about ansible as much as it is about you understanding how docker works

Comment: thanks @mdaniel for suggestion updated my question now can do you have answer of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a docker registry, just do this:

#### first: add a docker register on your machine.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart always --name registry registry:2
```

#### second: push your image to localhost.

```
docker tag ipdata:latest localhost:5000/ipdata:latest 
docker push localhost:5000/ipdata:latest
```

command upon the `localhost` is just push your docker image into docker registry on your machine.
assume your machine ipaddress is 10.10.1.12, then run command blow on your server side.

#### thrid: pull it

```
docker pull 10.10.1.12:5000/ipdata:latest
```

if you are using it without https, maybey you will meet issue blow:
[Private registry push fail: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874)

just flow solution blow to change your docker client config on your server side. it will be ok.
https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874#issuecomment-237194314

Comment: What gives you the impression that the user has a _docker registry_ running on their machine, or that it would be running on port 5000? I don't see any such detail in the original question

Comment: didn't get where to put the last one command with ip .? can you please edit above plybookcode and share here

Comment: thanks for answer this was the reason i was trying to push image from local rather then from registry . after doing this it worked like charm . thanks alot man

Comment: glad I was able to help : )